# Share article from webapp to native facebook

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

If I want to share some string from a mobile web page, is there any way to launch user's native facebook app to share ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way. Prefilling is not allowed anyway according to the platform policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/